# Why does LXC fail to start because of "Too many levels of symbolic links" but does start on the second or third try?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, nfs, lxc

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with LXC 1.07 and I'd like to access directories from within my lxc-container (ubuntu template) which are NFS mounts managed by autofs on the host.

Lets say the host has 3 different NFS-shares mounted by autofs:

auto.vol:

```
/vol/server1 -fstype=nfs IPserver1:/vol/server1
/vol/server2 -fstype=nfs IPserver2:/vol/server2
/vol/server3 -fstype=nfs IPserver3:/vol/server3
```

Now I try to access these from within my container, config looks like this:

```
lxc.mount.entry = /vol/server1     vol/server1 none bind 0 0
lxc.mount.entry = /vol/server2     vol/server2 none bind 0 0
lxc.mount.entry = /vol/server3     vol/server3 none bind 0 0
```

Now the problem is this does only work the second or third time I start the container, most of the time LXC complains about 'Too many levels of symbolic links' and quits. This is the output:

```
lxc-start: conf.c: mount_entry: 2049 Too many levels of symbolic links - failed to mount '/vol/server1' on '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxc/vol/server1'
lxc-start: conf.c: lxc_setup: 4163 failed to setup the mount entries for 'vm.local'
lxc-start: start.c: do_start: 688 failed to setup the container
lxc-start: sync.c: __sync_wait: 51 invalid sequence number 1. expected 2
```

The second time I start the container it complains about /vol/server2 and so on until it finally works as expected.

what is the problem and why does it work as I start it more often?

Comment: I have had this issue with autofs / lxc for years.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the nice users of the lxc-user mailinglist, I know now what the problem was.

It seems that autofs on the host is not fast enough to mount the directories and thats why the container complains. At the next attempt the previous lxc.mount.entry has been mounted by autofs and so on.

The solution seems to be to get rid of autofs or to invoke 'ls /vol/server' on the host so that autofs has some time to do its work, before stating the container.